# Reshape Wide to Long in R and include Sequence Number

Tags: r, reshape

I am looking to take data that is currently wide and melt it into a long format.  The trick is that I want to create a sequence indicator.

Here are my data:

```
df.wide <- data.frame(id = 1:5, 
                      code1 = sample(month.abb, 5),
                      code2 = sample(month.abb, 5))
```

What I am looking for:

```
   id rank value
1   1    1       Dec
2   1    2       Jan
3   2    1       May
4   2    2       Jun
5   3    1       Aug
6   3    2       Aug
7   4    1       Sep
8   4    2       Mar
9   5    1       Dec
10  5    2       Nov
```

I suspect that I could use this:

```
melt(df.wide, id=c("id"))
```

and iterate over the data aftewards to clean up the results, but I know reshape is a great package and wanted to ask before I reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a one-liner using the `reshape` function in `base` R (not to be confused with the `reshape` package)

```
reshape(df.wide, varying = 2:3, timevar = 'rank', sep = "", direction = 'long')
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you're on track.

```
df.melt <- melt(df.wide, idvar='id', variable_name='rank')
df.melt$rank <- gsub('code', '', df.melt$rank)
```

No need to iterate per say.

You could also use:

```
levels(df.melt$rank) <- 1:2
```

But, notice both versions give characters rather than numbers. wrap the `gsub` in `as.numeric()` if you need numbers.